# Windows Explorer in Win10 does not show all PCs on the Ethernet network

Tags: ethernet

I have a small peer-to-peer network with two Win10 PCs (call them A & B) and two Win7 PCs (C & D), a laser printer and a Broadband router (plus a laptop on occasion) all wired through an eight-port Ethernet switch.
Both Win10 PCs only show one Win7 (C) and one Win10 (B) - the same two on both - ie Win10 PC A does not appear in its own Windows Explorer Network directory. The Win7 PC shows all machines on the network.
If I want to attach a file to an email on Win10 PC B, then the directory that is brought up in Thunderbird does have Win10 PC A.
I have followed the procedure:
ipconfig /flushdns:
ipconfig /registerdns:
ipconfig /release:
ipconfig /renew:
and reboot on both Win10 PCs but the situation remains the same - what else can I try?

Comment: You probably should get two devices working and then go from there. Windows 7 may still be using SMBv1 which is a security risk. On Windows 10 machines, make sure Network discovery is enabled. Make sure you are not trying to use Homegroup (discontinued).

Answer (score 0):

I have manage to restore the missing Win10 PC to Windows Explorer in both Win10 machines by re-entering the computer and workgroup names in System Properties/Network ID, even though these details are already there.